# Stripping characters out of a dataframe and converting remaining characters to a float

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Looking to strip out the pound sterling character from an entire column in my pandas dataframe, and convert the remaining string into a float.

I've tried a replace method, and I've tried a split method.

```py
OA_data['COST (£) charged to Wellcome (inc VAT when charged)'] = OA_data.loc[OA_data['COST (£) charged to Wellcome (inc VAT when charged)']
    .astype(str)
    .str.contains('£'),'COST (£) charged to Wellcome (inc VAT when charged)']
    .replace('£','')
```

OA_data['COST (£) charged to Wellcome (inc VAT when charged)'] = OA_data['COST (£) charged to Wellcome (inc VAT when charged)'].str.split('£', expand=True)

I expect a dataframe column of strings which don't have the pound sterling sign, but the actual result for both methods is a column which still contains the pound sterling sign.

Comment: Can you show the dataframe you created, part of it? Also the code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
OA_data['COST (£) charged to Wellcome (inc VAT when charged)'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('£',' ')))
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['a']=['1£','3','5£','6 £']
df['a'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('£',' ')))
```

---

```
df['a']

Output:

0    1.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    6.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Keep in mind that you have to remove all characters so if there is any other one, it must also be removed.

I imagine that from the name of the columns you will not want to delete it.